# Getting a specific value from excel chart with vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get a specific value from an excel chart. This is the code which creates my chart (I created a reversed binomial distribution plot) :

```
Dim lim As String
Dim N As Long
N = Range("C4").Value

Dim x, s, p As Double
x = Range("C6") 'event number
s = Range("C5") 'sample size

Dim g() As Long
Dim h() As Double
Dim k() As Double
Dim prob() As Double

ReDim g(N)
ReDim prob(N)
ReDim h(N)
ReDim k(N)

For i = 1 To N
   g(i) = i
   h(i) = i / N
   k(i) = 1 - h(i)
   prob(i) = WorksheetFunction.BinomDist(x, s, h(i), False) * 100
 End If
```

And here is chart: [image]

I need the point where y is 0 on distribution curve second time.

Comment: Hi, is this all of your Code? Or is there more in the For Loop?

Comment: this is all of my code.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your `For` Loop, you could check `if prob(i) = 0 And Prob(i-1) > 0`, and save the index of this point. It's "too" simple, yet if this is just for this kind of distribution, it do the job :

```
Dim targetIndex As Integer
For i = 1 To N
   g(i) = i
   h(i) = i / N
   k(i) = 1 - h(i)
   prob(i) = WorksheetFunction.BinomDist(x, s, h(i), False) * 100

   If i > 1 Then    'check if this is not the first point
       If prob(i) = 0 And prob(i-1) <> 0 Then targetIndex = i
   End If
Next

'// Now your point is the couple (targetIndex, prob(targetIndex))
```